# Неожиданный результат  регулярного выражения

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть код:

```
$str="dfgdfgdfg <{nameuser}> <{user}> dfgdfgdfg";
$arrMatches=array();
$pattern="/([<][\{][a-z]+[\}][>])/";
preg_match($pattern,$str,$arrMatches);
foreach($arrMatches as &$val) 
    echo $val."<br/>";
```

Результат:

```
<{nameuser}>
<{nameuser}>
```

Ожидаемый результат:

```
<{nameuser}>
<{user}>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Не паникуем раньше времени, всё в порядке!

Код на [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/5HvO0T)

P.S.: используйте функцию preg_match_all